# CSS tabs wrap around right side of DIV with text transformation (rotatation)?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have tabs on the top of a page and if there is not enough room for those tabs, the tabs would then wrap around that DIV and would be text-transformed to rotate 90 degrees. My page is a CSS liquid design that is flexible based on window size. I would not like to use images since the tab text will be populated from a database. Below is a screenshot of would I would like to accomplish. I am also using PHP so, I could build some IF/THEN statements if needed. I would prefer to not use Javascript.

If window is open wide, display as:

[image]

If window is open narrow, display as:

[image]

I would like to use Listamatic (http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal05.htm) and somehow update it to allow for this new wrapping effect with text transformation. Is this possible?

Here is part of the CSS that might work:

```
.sidetabs {
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

**Update: 12/13/2011:** CSS - Force a child DIV to expand page width?

Minitech: Thank you for the insight and the Javascript example. In an effort, to solve my tab issue, I thought I might try another approach.

I am working on an editable navigation. The user can add many tabs across the top as they wish. In the event that there are many tabs that would force the set of tabs to be broken/wrapped to the next line, I would like to force it on 1 line even if this means that the page width would grow immensely.

Is there a way for a child DIV to expand a page width even if the content is in a wrapper? In my JS Fiddle link below, I have a simple wrapper page with a right sidenav. I am using Listamatic tabs (http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal05.htm) for the top. As you can see, the tabs are breaking into many rows of tabs and it doesn't look great. Can I use some CSS to force the DIV to not wrap onto a 2nd or 3rd line? I would like the DIV to be liquid based on the number of tabs (and length of the text in the tab text). Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/zenfiddle/yUPCC/3/

Comment: IE really doesn't like CSS3, so watch out. It's normally a lot of JavaScript to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I know, that's completely impossible using CSS, as well as using PHP, since it's a server-side scripting language. You'll need to use JavaScript in this instance, and of course make sure you degrade gracefully all the same.

A simple way might be to check for wrapping elements using `offsetTop`. Something like this (you'll have to adjust for positioning if you use that):

```
var navigation = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].getElementsByTagName('a'); // Or however you want to do this
var i, element;

for(i = 0; element = navigation[i]; i++) {
    if(element.offsetTop > 0) {
        // It's a wrapping element
        element.className = element.className ? element.className + ' side-tab' : 'side-tab';
    }
}
```

Then, you can style `nav a` (for example) and `nav a.side-tab` however you need.

Comment: Minitech: Thank you for the insight and the Javascript example. In an effort, to solve my tab issue, I thought I might try another approach. Please see my update above (Update: 12/13/2011).